# SQL search with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: beer and brewery

```
Schema::create('breweries', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
   $table->foreign( 'user_id' )
         ->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' )
         ->onUpdate( 'cascade' );
   $table->string('brewery_name');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('beer', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->unsignedInteger('brewery_id');
   $table->foreign( 'brewery_id' )
         ->references( 'id' )->on( 'breweries' )
         ->onUpdate( 'cascade' );
   $table->string('beer_name');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to search on beer_name and brewery_name.

For only searching on beer_name, I'm using the following query:

```
$beer = Beer::where('user_id', Auth::id())
         ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
           $query->where('beer_name','LIKE','%'.$search."%")
                 ->orWhere('brewery_id','LIKE','%'.$search."%")
        })->get();
```

and this works fine as both 'beer_name' and 'brewery_id' are fields of the beer table.

How can I change this query so that I search also on 'brewery_name' (=part of brewery table) instead of brewery_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was tagged SQL I answer with an Sql query rather than with php(?) code

```
SELECT * 
FROM beer b
JOIN breweries r ON r.id = b.brewery_id
WHERE b.beer_name LIKE ?
   OR r.brewery_name LIKE ?
```

Replace ? with beer search term and brewery search term respectively

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the SQL query is what I was looking for